# Is there any way to run super-privileged containers using Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want the all processes within the pod see the same network and process table, as well as share any IPCs with the host processes. 
I know it possible when we use docker by leveraging the following command.

```
docker run -it --privileged --ipc=host --net=host --pid=host   \
           -v /:/host -v /run:/run -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime   \
           --name privcontainer centos7 /bin/bash
```

On the other hand, is there any way to run super-privileged containers using Kubernetes?
If possible, I would like to know the way to write pod yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `privileged` flag on the `SecurityContext` of the container spec.

Check out [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#privileged-mode-for-pod-containers) for more details.

I could only find an example from the v1.4 docs:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello-world
spec:
  containers:
    - name: hello-world-container
      # The container definition
      # ...
      securityContext:
        privileged: true   ###Here is what you are looking for
        seLinuxOptions:
          level: "s0:c123,c456"
```

Even [more infos here](https://kubernetes-v1-4.github.io/docs/user-guide/security-context/)

I'm sure you're aware, but as a general word of caution, the privileged will remove all container security settings and open up the cluster to potential security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks! However,  I think "privileged: true" option just turns off the security separation, meaning a process running as root inside of the container has the same access to the host that it would have if it were run outside the container. In addition, I would like to turn off PID namespace as well. This means that the processes within the container see the same process table with the host processes.

Comment: Process namespace sharing became possible in the meantime via [`shareProcessNamespace: true`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/share-process-namespace/)

Answer (score 1):

To disable the namespacing of a container PIDs, and thus allowing this container to view all processes on a host, you need to specify `hostPID: true` in the pod specs.

You might find this manifest useful if you want to inspect a Kubernetes host from within a pod:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: debug
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: debug
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: debug
      name: debug
    spec:
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      hostNetwork: true
      hostPID: true
      containers:
      - name: linux
        image: alpine
        args:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
          runAsGroup: 0
          runAsUser: 0
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt/host
          name: host
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /
          type: ""
        name: host
```

This will instantiate a "debug" pod on each node on your cluster (including control-plane node if they are visible to you). This pod will have access to all PIDs from the host, will see all its networks, and the node filesystem will be browseable at `/mnt/host`.